# How to convert all the column data in snowflake/database to upper case with a with a single query in Snowsql?

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowsql

I would like to convert all the data if in **lower case in snowflake table to upper case.**

I have multiple catalogs, schemas and then tables. Would like to do this with Python.

Is **there a straight query on table to convert** all the data (columns) into upper case?

I have the following query, but I would like to do it for a specific data type and for only data that

is lower case(If this is faster) else for the entire table..

UPDATE MyTable

SET    MyColumn = UPPER(MyColumn)

WHERE  MyColumn != UPPER(MyColumn) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

How do I do it for multiple columns at once for the table??

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of here is get all the columns from information_schema like this

```
select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <>
```

Once you get the query result of columns formulate your SELECT statement by using UPPER(<column_a>) dynamically.

This can be done in python(as this seems to be your choice here) easily.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate on "Once you get the query result of columns formulate your SELECT statement by using UPPER(<column_a>) dynamically". would it be ok to share an example?